# How to create a regex that would include anything after a string

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I'm creating a goal and I need the first step to include a string and anything afterwards. Does anyone know how to do this? I thought it would be this /campsites/uk/?(.*) but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: Can you provide a simple input and desired output?

Comment: I want to include any traffic that starts with /campsites/uk/
There are quite a lot of URL's that are formatted this way, therefore, I was wondering if there is a way to create a regex that would include any URLs that start with that string. I hope that helps @MaxZoom

Comment: Try `^campsites/uk(/.*)?$`. When saying "doesn't work", what do you mean?

Comment: When I said that it doesn't work, I meant that I included my original expression 2 days ago and I had a look at the funnel and it hasn't populated

Comment: @melishatrout The use of character `?` in your regex is for the URL parameters (query) or something else?

Comment: @MaxZoom sorry it's not meant to be a query, I searched for an answer and I thought that it would work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In regular expression the special characters must be escaped with the `\` slash

You may review this [tutorial](http://www.lunametrics.com/regex-book/Regular-Expressions-Google-Analytics.pdf) on how to use regex in Google Analytics

However based on provided examples, your regex should look like

```
/campsites/uk/(.*)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kMSTVs/2) website with the regex explanation

Comment: Glad I could help. Welcome to the Stack Overflow!